# CentOS - Yum - Multiple urls

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

Is it possible to have multiple entries in same conf file, each with different baseurls, but be able to call them using a common name? Example:

Before:

```
[centos_os]
baseurl=foo.com/centos/os

[centos_updates]
baseurl=foo.com/centos/updates

[centos_extras]
baseurl=foo.com/centos/extras
```

After:

```
[centos_all]
baseurl=foo.com/centos/os
baseurl=foo.com/centos/updates
baseurl=foo.com/centos/extras
```

And call them with one command like `--enablerepo=centos_all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the repos with a pattern:

```
 yum --enablerepo=centos_\* install package
```

but not under one name.